# Cppreference.com или cplusplus.com ?

Tags: c++

Пользуюсь cplusplus.com, не всегда вдаваясь в подробности, но вот недавно услышал про  cppreference.com. Так вот в чем их разница? В гугле смог найти только то, что на cplusplus.com бывают ошибки. Хотелось бы услышать ваше мнение.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На stackoverflow не рекомендуют cplusplus.com:

- [Why is the cplusplus website bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11972076/why-is-the-cplusplus-website-bad)
- [cplusplus.com is bad and you should feel bad](http://kera.name/articles/2013/02/cplusplus-com-is-bad-and-you-should-feel-bad/)

Comment: @VladD, только вот информация на cppreference.com заформализована до невозможности и организована так, что до примеров, как что-то начать писать не доберешься.

--

Сравните, например multimap на cplusplus.com (правда его там еще надо отыскать внутри раздела про map) и cppreference.com

Comment: @avp: С этой точки зрения вы правы, но, с другой стороны, на cppreference вы найдёте ответ на вопрос, что такое [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), и что из них инициализирует объект нулями (и в чём разница между `new T` и `new T()`), а cplusplus об этом и подобном молчит.

Comment: Согласен. Видимо надо как-то пользоваться обеими (а лучше вообще не использовать кресты).

Comment: @avp: угу, C++ чересчур сложен в синтаксисе (почему, зачем, какого чёрта `new T`, `new T()` и `new T(arg)` имеют все три различную семантику?).

Answer (score 2):

Принцип разный. Один ресурс частный, второй - общественный, на движке Wiki: правь кто хошь. При этом ни один из них не застрахован от ошибок, а стандарт не регламентирует 100% возможных ситуаций (помимо UB).

В качестве подсказок использую оба. Плюс еще MSDN.