# Вызов конструктора без скобок

Tags: c++

У меня родился вопрос по мотивам вот [этого вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/242204/c-cppreference-com-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-cplusplus-com) а точнее комментариев к ним.

Итак вопрос: в чем разница между `new T` и `new T()`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Смотрите.

`new T` — это [default initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_initialization). При этом происходит следующее:

- для класса `T` вызывается [*конструктор по умолчанию*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) (то есть, конструктор без параметров или конструктор с параметрами, который *может быть* вызван без параметров т. к. все аргументы имеют значение по умолчанию)
- для массива `T` ко всем элементам массива рекурсивно применяется default initialization
- для остальных `T` (например, простых типов), ничего не происходит, значение не определено.

`new T()` — это [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization). Оно работает так:

- если `T` — класс, и у него есть хоть один явно определённый конструктор, то вызывается конструктор по умолчанию (см. выше).
- если `T` — класс, но не union, и у него нету явно определённых конструкторов, то у него есть автоматически созданный конструктор по умолчанию. Объект сначала подвергается [*нулевой инициализации*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) (в большинстве случаев, но не всегда, просто память прописывается нулями), а затем вызывается конструктор по умолчанию.
- если `T` — массив, ко всем элементам массива рекурсивно применяется value initialization
- в остальных случаях (например, если `T` — простой тип), он подвергается нулевой инициализации.

Пример:

```
int* p1 = new int;
int* p2 = new int();
```

Здесь значение `*p1` не определено, а значение `*p2` гарантированно 0.

---

Для полноты:

`new T(arg)` — это [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization). Происходит следующее:

- если `T` — класс, рассматриваются все конструкторы и вызывается наиболее подходящий
- иначе `T` должен быть простым типом, и значение `arg` приводится к типу `T` (используя, если нужно, [неявные преобразования](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast)), и результат будет значением объекта.

Заметьте, что в этом случае для классов нулевая инициализация не выполняется, в отличие от случая без параметров, но со скобками.

Comment: А new T(arg) просто в том вопросе написано, что эти три конструкции имеют разную семантику

Comment: @ReinRaus: дополнил ответ

Comment: @VladD, спасибо.

Comment: спасибо за рассказ)

Comment: @Andy_Reed: пожалуйста!