# Ошибка компиляции: Выражение должно представлять класс или структуру

Tags: c++, visual-c++

При компиляции выдаётся следующая ошибка:

> выражение слева от .print должно представлять класс, структуру или объединение.

Код:

```
class Object
{
private:
    char* name;
    char* teacher;
    short int hours;
    char* exam;
    float mark;

public:
    Object::Object()
    {
        Object::name = "unknown"; 
        Object::teacher = "unknown";
        Object::hours = 0;
        Object::exam = "unknown";
        Object::mark = 0;
    }

    Object::Object(char *n)
    {
        Object::name = n;
        Object::teacher = "Unknown";
        Object::hours = 0;
        Object::exam = "unknown";
        Object::mark = 0;
    }

    void Object::print()
    {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << teacher << std::endl;
        std::cout << hours << std::endl;
        std::cout << exam << std::endl;
        std::cout << mark << std::endl;
    }
};

void main()
{
    Object Program1();
    Program1.print();
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, не совсем ясно, зачем в конструкторах упорно исползуются квалифицированные имена членов класса. Во-вторых, в С++ уже запрещено указывать на строковые литералы неконстантными указателями. Ну и, разумеется, `void main` режет глаз.

Comment: @AnT это ж Студия, тут много чего глаз режет. Но не применительно к Студии, глаз режет форматирование отступов.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это канонический пример [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse). Вы, согласно правилам языка, объявили не экземпляр класса, а прототип функции с пустым списком аргументов, возвращающей `Object`.

Уберите лишние скобки после `Program1`.

```
Object Program1;
```

---

Уточнение: чтобы не думать о случае отсутствия конструкторов, лучше писать так: `Object Program1{};` (по причинам, сходным с [этими](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/242505/10105)), если ваша версия компилятора это позволяет.

Answer (score 1):

Этот код вообще не соберётся... (в gcc точно)

1) Не нужно везде писать Object:: внутри класса

2) main() должна возвращать int

3) Object Program1(); переделайте в  Object Program1;

Вобщем вот так...

```
  #include <iostream>

class Object
{
private:
    char* name;
    char* teacher;
    short int hours;
    char* exam;
    float mark;

public:
    Object()
    {
        name = "unknown";
        teacher = "unknown";
        hours = 0;
        exam = "unknown";
        mark = 0;
    }

    Object(char *n)
    {
        name = n;
        teacher = "Unknown";
        hours = 0;
        exam = "unknown";
        mark = 0;
    }

    void print()
    {
        std::cout << name << std::endl;
        std::cout << teacher << std::endl;
        std::cout << hours << std::endl;
        std::cout << exam << std::endl;
        std::cout << mark << std::endl;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Object Program1(void);
    Program1.print();
    return 1;
}
```

По поводу скобочек...

Вы сделали не то что хотели. Хотели вызвать конструктор объекта,а у вас получилось объявление функции.

```
Object Program1(void);
```

п.с. Мне кажется у Вас какая-то неправильная книжка по c++...