# варианты инициализации объектов

Tags: c++

Начал изучать `c++`. Может кто подробно объяснить чем отличаются эти варианты инициализации? Когда что вызывается и т.п.?

```
 Type x =  smth ; 
 Type x   (smth);  
 Type x = {smth}; 
 Type x   {smth};
 Type x = (smth);
```

Comment: Тут многое зависит от того, что представляет собой Type.:) Почитайте по этой ссылке в конце темы о различиях в инициализации.  http://cpp.forum24.ru/?1-3-0-00000047-000-10001-0-1475597138

Comment: @VladfromMoscow мне бы на более примитивном уровне...

Comment: Вот ещё немного по связанной теме: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/242499/10105

Comment: @user226016 Как раз в ссылке, которую я предоставил в сообщении, которое содержит заголовок "Метаморфозы инициализации" написано без копания в деталях, а выделено главные различия. Тема эта на самом деле большая, поэтому ваш вопрос слишком широкий.

Comment: @VladD спасибо! а для фигурных скобок?

Comment: @user226016: Это aggregate initialization, описано [здесь](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). (Она не подходила в рамки того вопроса, т. к. без `new`.)

Comment: @VladD, это не всегда aggregate initialization

Comment: @ixSci: А что это тогда? Можно ссылку хоть куда-нибудь почитать?

Comment: @VladD, с фигурными это может быть либо [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), либо [copy initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), это в добавок к aggregate и паре list direct & copy

Comment: @ixSci: Ужас! Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

У интуристов было обсуждение тут [Initialization difference with or without Curly braces in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21150067/initialization-difference-with-or-without-curly-braces-in-c11)

Если коротко, то инициализация {} не даст произвести "сужающих" преобразований. То есть ты не сможешь присвоить таким образом int char'у

Comment: int char'у присвоить можно, если он не требует narrowing conversion.

Comment: так я об этом и написал, можно char i ={22}, можно unsigned char i = {222}. Но нельзя char i = {222}, хотя char i = 222 сработает.

Comment: Просто у Вас написано, что _«не сможешь присвоить таким образом int char'у»_, а это не так, что Вы сами и показали: `char i ={22}` — здесь происходит присвоение int'а, char'у. Я понимаю, что Вы имели в виду, но в текущей формулировке это не совсем корректно.

Comment: ... не даст произвести "сужающих" .... _таким_образом_ ... Ну не знаю, наверное "таким образом" нужно было выделить как-то. Я подумал и так будет понятно.